# Register static class method as shutdown function in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP is it possible to register a shutdown function (with `register_shutdown_function()`) which is a static method implemented in a class? I mean something like this:

```
//index.php
require_once("modules/Analyzer/Analyzer.php");
register_shutdown_function("Analyzer::log_shutdown");

//Analyzer.php
class Analyzer {
   ...

   public static function log_shutdown(){
      // do some awesome stuff
      Analyzer::screenshot();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Paul Crovella First I thought it won't work, but then I figured out it was a typo, and worked properly!

Answer (score 15):

The first argument passed to register_shutdown_function is of the type [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). A callable static method looks like this:

```
register_shutdown_function(array('Analyzer', 'log_shutdown'));
```

As of PHP 5.2.3 it may also look exactly like what you originally posted

Comment: @PaulCrovella you're right; didn't realize that. Added to answer

Answer (score 11):

Can use an anonymous function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    Analyzer::log_shutdown();
});
```

also, in analyzer you can use a call to the same class like this:

```
class Analyzer{
    public static function log_shutdown(){
        self::screenshot();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually via namespace:

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    \app\modules\Analyzer\Analyzer::log_shutdown();
});
```

or

```
register_shutdown_function(['\app\modules\Analyzer\Analyzer', 'log_shutdown']);
register_shutdown_function(["\\app\\modules\\Analyzer\\Analyzer", "log_shutdown"]);
```